How to get shadow for \tcboxmath?
I have a tex file of beamer class
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{equation} \label{main_eq4a}
\tcboxmath[colback=fondo,frame empty]{
d X_t = b(t, X_t, \textcolor{magenta}{\ell_t (X_t), \mu_t}) d t + \sqrt{2} d B_t .
}
\end{equation}

Equation \eqref{main_eq4a} is an SDE.

\end{frame}
\end{document}


Could you explain how to get the same shadow as below?

I tried option drop shadow but to no avail.

You need the enhanced skin.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}
\colorlet{ombra}{black}

\newcommand{\akiramath}[2][]{%
  \tcboxmath[
    enhanced,
    colback=fondo,
    frame empty,
    fuzzy shadow={0.5mm}{-0.5mm}{0.3mm}{1pt}{ombra},
    #1
]{\displaystyle #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{equation} \label{main_eq4a}
\akiramath{
  d X_t = b(t, X_t, \mathcolor{magenta}{\ell_t (X_t), \mu_t}) d t + \sqrt{2} d B_t .
}
\end{equation}

Equation \eqref{main_eq4a} is an SDE.

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you very much for your help. Now I am ready for my presentation tomorrow :)
